# ¿Cómo corregir este error 1064 con trigger en MARIADB v10.5.15? funciona en 10.1.31

Tags: mysql, trigger

Mi pregunta es acerca de triggers en mysql/mariadb. Hice un programa para control de inventario con mariadb 10.1.31 y funciona de manera correcta, el problema es que con la nueva versión de mariadb 10.5.15 me arroja codigo 1064 y no puedo localizar el bug. A continuación se muestra el script de las tablas con datos

```
/*
SQLyog Ultimate v13.1.1 (32 bit)
MySQL - 10.1.31-MariaDB : Database - salud_capital_auto
*********************************************************************
*/

/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=''*/;

/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
USE `inventario`;

/*Table structure for table `detalle_planilla_orden` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `detalle_planilla_orden`;

CREATE TABLE `detalle_planilla_orden` (
  `id_transa` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_solicitud` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_orden` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_centro_acopio` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_centro` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_tipo_renglon` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_renglon` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_frecuencia` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cantidad` double(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_usua` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_transa`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_transa` (`id_transa`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Data for the table `detalle_planilla_orden` */

insert  into `detalle_planilla_orden`(`id_transa`,`id_solicitud`,`id_orden`,`id_centro_acopio`,`id_centro`,`id_tipo_renglon`,`id_renglon`,`id_frecuencia`,`cantidad`,`id_usua`) values 
(1,1,24,1,1,NULL,1,1,1.00,622),
(2,1,24,1,1,NULL,12,1,2.00,622),
(3,1,24,1,1,NULL,82,1,1.00,622),
(4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,93.00,622),
(6,2,27,105,1,NULL,4,3,2.00,622),
(7,1,26,105,1,2,237,3,2.00,622),
(8,1,1,1,1,1,17,1,2.00,622),
(10,1,1,1,1,1,5,1,18.00,622),
(12,3,28,105,1,1,17,9,20.00,622);

/*Table structure for table `historico_inventario` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `historico_inventario`;

CREATE TABLE `historico_inventario` (
  `id_detalle` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_transaccion` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_centro_acopio` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_proveedor` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_movimiento` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_tipo_renglon` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_renglon` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_grupo_etario` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `empaque` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_clase_medicamento` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombre_medicamento` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unidad_medida` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `presentacion` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cantidad_por_present` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cantidad_unidad_medida` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cantidad_total_por_presentacion` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cantidad_existencia` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_elaboracion` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_vencimiento` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `lote` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `costo_empaque` double(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cantidad_bs` double(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_costo` double(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `minimo_existencia` double(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo_existencia` enum('1','2') DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_usua` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Data for the table `historico_inventario` */

insert  into `historico_inventario`(`id_detalle`,`id_transaccion`,`id_centro_acopio`,`id_proveedor`,`fecha_movimiento`,`id_tipo_renglon`,`id_renglon`,`id_grupo_etario`,`empaque`,`id_clase_medicamento`,`nombre_medicamento`,`unidad_medida`,`presentacion`,`cantidad_por_present`,`cantidad_unidad_medida`,`cantidad_total_por_presentacion`,`cantidad_existencia`,`fecha_elaboracion`,`fecha_vencimiento`,`lote`,`costo_empaque`,`cantidad_bs`,`total_costo`,`minimo_existencia`,`tipo_existencia`,`id_usua`) values 
(1,1,105,NULL,'2022-03-14',1,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'UND',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,19993,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,37.00,NULL,NULL,NULL,692),
(3,1,105,NULL,'2022-03-17',1,5,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'UND',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,9998,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0.85,NULL,NULL,NULL,622),
(4,1,105,NULL,'2022-04-04',1,17,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'UND',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,10485,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1.45,NULL,NULL,NULL,622),
(5,1,105,NULL,'2022-04-04',2,223,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'UND',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,80,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,4.00,NULL,NULL,NULL,622),
(6,1,105,NULL,'2022-04-04',2,224,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'UND',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,120,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,8.00,NULL,NULL,NULL,622),
(13,NULL,1,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);

/*Table structure for table `salidas_almacen` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `salidas_almacen`;

CREATE TABLE `salidas_almacen` (
  `id_solicitud` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_orden` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_centro_acopio` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_centro` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_tipo_renglon` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_renglon` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cantidad_despachada` double(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_despacho` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_usua` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Data for the table `salidas_almacen` */

insert  into `salidas_almacen`(`id_solicitud`,`id_orden`,`id_centro_acopio`,`id_centro`,`id_tipo_renglon`,`id_renglon`,`cantidad_despachada`,`fecha_despacho`,`id_usua`) values 
(1,24,NULL,NULL,1,12,2.00,'2022-03-16',NULL),
(1,24,NULL,NULL,1,82,1.00,'2022-03-16',NULL),
(1,1,NULL,NULL,1,72,2.00,'2022-03-19',NULL),
(1,1,NULL,NULL,1,73,1.00,'2022-03-19',NULL),
(1,26,NULL,NULL,1,5,10.00,'2022-03-28',NULL),
(2,27,NULL,NULL,1,4,2.00,'2022-03-28',NULL),
(3,28,NULL,NULL,1,14,2.00,'2022-03-29',NULL),
(1,26,NULL,NULL,1,5,2.00,'2022-03-31',NULL),
(1,1,NULL,NULL,1,17,2.00,'2022-05-10',NULL),
(1,1,NULL,NULL,1,1,40.00,'2022-05-11',NULL),
(1,1,NULL,NULL,1,5,18.00,'2022-05-11',NULL),
(1,1,NULL,NULL,1,1,19995.00,'2022-05-12',NULL),
(3,28,NULL,NULL,1,17,505.00,'2022-05-13',NULL),
(3,28,NULL,NULL,1,17,20.00,'2022-05-13',NULL),
(1,1,NULL,NULL,1,1,93.00,'2022-05-16',NULL),
(1,1,NULL,NULL,1,1,20000.00,'2022-05-16',NULL),
(1,1,NULL,NULL,1,1,20.00,'2022-05-16',NULL),
(1,1,NULL,NULL,1,1,30000.00,'2022-05-16',NULL);
```

Mi trigger es el siguiente:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `nombre de la base de datos`$$  

DROP TRIGGER  `completar_orden`$$ 

CREATE TRIGGER `completar_orden` BEFORE INSERT ON `detalle_planilla_orden` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET @id_solicitud =new.id_solicitud;
SET @id_orden =new.id_orden; 
SET @id_centro_acopio=new.id_centro_acopio; 
SET @id_tipo_renglon = new.id_tipo_renglon; 
SET @id_renglon = new.id_renglon; 
SET @cantidad_despachada =new.cantidad; 
SET @fecha_despacho =NOW(); 
SET @rowcnt=0; 
SET @existencia_anterior=0; 
/*Determina existencia del renglon en el Inventario*/ 
SET @existencia_anterior = (SELECT SUM(historico_inventario.cantidad_existencia) 
FROM historico_inventario WHERE id_tipo_renglon = @id_tipo_renglon AND id_renglon = @id_renglon AND id_centro_acopio=@id_centro_acopio); 
/*Evalua si el inventario cubre la cantidad solicitada en el pedido*/   
  (SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @rowcnt FROM historico_inventario 
   WHERE historico_inventario.id_tipo_renglon = @id_tipo_renglon AND historico_inventario.id_renglon = @id_renglon AND cantidad_existencia <> 0 AND @cantidad_despachada > @existencia_anterior AND id_centro_acopio=@id_centro_acopio); 
   IF @rowcnt=1 THEN 
      CALL santo_tomas(); 
     ELSE 
     INSERT INTO salidas_almacen(id_solicitud,id_orden,id_tipo_renglon,id_renglon,cantidad_despachada,fecha_despacho) 
     VALUES  (@id_solicitud,@id_orden,@id_tipo_renglon,@id_renglon,@cantidad_despachada,@fecha_despacho);   
     UPDATE historico_inventario
     SET cantidad_existencia = (@existencia_anterior - @cantidad_despachada)
     WHERE historico_inventario.id_tipo_renglon = @id_tipo_renglon AND historico_inventario.id_renglon = @id_renglon AND id_centro_acopio=@id_centro_acopio;   
   END IF;
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

El código fuente lo verifique a nivel de sintaxis adicionalmente en
https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/
y en https://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/

Este es el error :

```
 queries executed, 2 success, 1 errors, 1 warnings

Query: USE `inventario`

0 row(s) affected

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0.001 sec
Total Time     : 0.001 sec
-----------------------------------------------------------

Query: DROP TRIGGER 0032 IF EXISTS */ `completar_orden`

0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s)

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 1.070 sec
Total Time     : 1.070 sec

Note Code : 1360
Trigger does not exist
-----------------------------------------------------------

Query: CREATE 0017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */ TRIGGER `completar_orden` BEFORE INSERT ON `detalle_planilla_orden` FOR EACH ROW BEG...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO @rowcnt FROM historico_inventario 
   WHERE historico_inventario.id_tip...' at line 18

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0 sec
```

Agradezco su opinión al respecto

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. POR FAVOR NO GRITES. Y por favor, pon el mensaje de error completo, no lo resumas. Puedes [edit] la pregunta, editar los gritos del título y poner el mensaje de error completo, por favor :)

Comment: Soy nuevo en su grupo ahora agrego el texto del error, Gracias

Comment: Por qué necesitas paréntesis alrededor de ese SELECT ... INTO? Lo otro: en el ELSE hay un carácter extraño ```ELSE ` ```

Comment: Ese carácter lo puse involuntariamente, el paréntesis es por el sub-query que hago en este bloque de codigo:

Comment: Tienes un SET @existencia_anterior... FROM WHERE, y después tienes ese SELECT INTO entre paréntesis. No veo subconsulta

Comment: Elimine los paréntesis de la sentencia: `(SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @rowcnt ... id_centro_acopio=@id_centro_acopio);`.

Comment: Gracias ya quite los paréntesis y lo genere sin error, esta noche lo pruebo y te aviso 20 puntos